# Having if or in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nan

In python 3.7 is there a way to check 2 conditions in a list comprehesion?

e.g If I had this to start with the follow which only ensures the value is NOT nan:

```
[1 if x is not np.nan else 0 for x in df["value"]]
```

But instead of only checking if the value is nan, I also want to check if it's nan or equal to "N". Something like:

```
[1 if (x is not np.nan) or (x != "N") else 0 for x in df["value"]]
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `is not np.nan` is not how you do a NaN check.

Comment: That's fine. The bigger issue is the fact that the conditional expression isn't necessary. `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so `True == 1` and `False == 0`. You can simply write `[x is not np.nan or x != "N" for x in df["value"]` to get a list of boolean values. Anything consuming the list expecting `1`s and `0`s should work the same with `True`s and `False`s.

Comment: This syntax should work fine.

Comment: @chepner: Not really. Plenty of Pandas/NumPy code treats booleans differently from ints (and `df` and `np` indicate this code is almost certainly using both those libraries (though not very well)). For example, indexing a NumPy array with an array of booleans does something very different from indexing it with an array of integers.

Comment: Also, even if the NaN issue didn't exist, `or` is the wrong operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `is` to check if a variable is `NaN` can be dangerous. Indeed, it will depend on which kind of `NaN` you are considering: is it from `math.nan` or `numpy.nan`?

A more robust solution is to use `numpy.isnan` / `pandas.isna` / `math.isnan` method. Here is an example with `numpy.isnan`:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

numpy_nan = np.nan
math_nan = math.nan

print(np.isnan(numpy_nan)) # True
print(numpy_nan is np.nan) # True

print(np.isnan(math_nan)) # True
print(math_nan is np.nan) # False
```

As you can see, the last example has been evaluated as `False` whereas I think you want to have this `True`

---

Then, to answer to your question: you can add a lot of different logic in a list comprehension. However, it can be hard to read for other users so in general a good practice is to define a small function with the logic. The list comprehension will be easier to understand:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [1, 0, np.nan]
    }
)

def is_valid(x):
    return not (np.isnan(x) or x == "N")

[1 if is_valid(x) else 0 for x in df["value"]] # [1, 1, 0]
```

---

Lastly, the if / else in the list comprehension seems to be useless in your case. Indeed, you are trying to convert a list of values to a list of 1 / 0 which is similar to a list of `True` / `False` so you can simply do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [1, 0, np.nan]
    }
)

def is_valid(x):
    return not (np.isnan(x) or x == "N")

[is_valid(x) for x in df["value"]] # [True, True, False]
```